# PayPal SDK sandbox brazilian acount payment error

Tags: android, paypal, payment, sandbox

Hi i create a brazilian premier sandbox account and when i try to pay with android app which i got on a github:

[PayPal Android Sample](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK)

When I try to buy a thing it gives the message:  ***error to process the payment,try again later***. 
But when i try with US account it works well.

```
private static PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration()

    // Start with mock environment.  When ready, switch to sandbox (ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX)
    // or live (ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION)
    .environment(PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX)

    .clientId("APP-80W284485P519544T");
```

I think it's something related with the currency set.

Someone know what was causing the error?

Comment: So, we're supposed to get an app you didn't develop and debug it for you?  No.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about debugging something the author has no part of (besides not understanding how it works)

Comment: Sorry kevin not want me to debug my problem is not the code. it works well but only for a PayPal account in sendbox that is configured to a user "US". I am developing my application and came across this error, just wanted to know if anyone has gone through this

Comment: We will not download some indeterminate application of unknown size and attempt to ascertain why it doesn't work, that's your job. Post some snippet of code that fails, explain what it should do, what it doesn't do and then see if we can help. Read the help page too so you can understand why you got this response.

Comment: Just to remind Kevin code contains no error, but when I start the activity from paypal it does not return any value as it should return. I found no answer anywhere to this problem, sorry if I was not clear enough

Comment: Do you have logs from the PayPal mSDK?  All errors are logged to the android logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but already clarified my doubts. PayPal has two ways to API's developments: The "**classic**" and "**REST**".
The classical way which in turn is older, it is possible to configure for all accounts of 190 countries, to develop a mobile application with that using the **classic API** you should use the library"MPL".([MPL library](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/mobile/ht_mpl-itemPayment-Android/)) But the great disadvantage of this method is that it does not offer the customer the option of paying directly with credit card statement.

The second way is to develop app with PayPal developing kite for **REST API** development. However despite this method to be younger, it just can be used for a US account. that's where came my mistake because I was trying to access with a Brazilian account